# Need to create a Bucket using a Calculated Column - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, calculated-columns, measure

Below is how my data looks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2UbW.png)

1. I need to create a Calculated ColumnF(Bucket) based on Date selection which I need to use in a Barchart (X- Axis)
2. For Example DateSelected = Jan1 & Jan2, Client = Client1 then Sessions should be = 11(1+10) and Bucket = 11 to 20
3. I am able to achieve this by creating Calculated Measure but not calculated Columns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORXGz.png)

Is there a dynamic way in Power BI that will update the column based on user selection

Comment: It's not possible for the calculated columns to respond to user selections. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148028/powerbi-calculatetable-filter-with-selectedvalue/70148616#70148616

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.