My Selected ID measure from a slicer is being returned correctly to a visual card but in DAX the measure is returning blank
My Measure
SelectedRace = IF(HASONEVALUE(Race[RaceID]), VALUES(FACTSectional[RaceID]), BLANK())
Adding a card to a canvas pointing to SelectedRace  when I select a different race number the card updates correctly
However in my dynamic table run by DAX  the Measure is returning a blank when I reference  it and no records are returned However hardcoding the RaceID works
Hardcoding works
VAR SelectedRaceID = 222633
But referencing the measure in the table DAX never picks it up
VAR SelectedRaceID  = [SelectedRace]
.
.
.
I am expecting rows returned to the table when I change the selected race but this only works when hardcoding the RaceID. For some reason DAX cant reference the value in the measure

What do you mean by "dynamic table"?

It is used to create a table from DAX as below:  See new attachments

Calculated tables are not dynamic, they are identical to the imported tables (the fact that you used DAX is irrelevant). Only measures are dynamic (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148028/powerbi-calculatetable-filter-with-selectedvalue/70148616#70148616)

Calculated tables and calculated columns in Power BI cannot be dynamic (i.e. change when you interact with the report), these are only calculated once at semantic model refresh time.
Measures are calculated at query time, that is, when you select a value in your slicer. You need to rethink your use-case to have anything dynamically displayed being calculated using measures. Probably measures that have some table-based components as VARs.
