In DAX, how to use TOPN but still be a SLICER-RESPONSIVE measure (like KEEPFILTERS)
I created multiple visualizations in this Power BI project, driven by DAX measures that are successfully filter-responsive:  when I use a filter (or slicer) on certain columns in the table, all visualizations change.
That filter-responsiveness was created by making sure all the needed data-tables contain certain flags, and then creating a "driver-table" for each flag.  Then I created a "relationship" for each flag, between the flag's driver-table and each data-table.
So that way, when I define an "all pages" filter for that flag, I make the filter select FROM THE DRIVER-TABLE.  Therefore, that flag selection selects all data-tables, affects all their measures, and therefore changes ALL THEIR VISUALIZATIONS.
But ... that's not working, for my "bottom 10" visualizations.  The problem is:  I've been asked to exclude the rows with ZERO counts.
I tried using the Power BI filter feature, to filter by TOP N, but then the zero count rows are selected.
I tried using TOPN in DAX for a table, but the problem with this, is that it's not filter-responsive:  KEEPFILTERS does not seem to be doing its job.
Here's an example that I made generic, of code like I tried, using TOPN:
TopN_table = 
    TOPN(5, 
        SUMMARIZE(
            FILTER(
                KEEPFILTERS('my_detail_data')
                , 'my_detail_data'[flag_a_4_member] = "Y" 
                && 'my_detail_data'[flag_b_4_line] = "Y"
            ),
            'my_detail_data'[text_col_to_group_1],
            'my_detail_data'[text_col_to_group_2],
            "summ_col_1", SUM('my_detail_data'[int_col_1]),
            "summ_col_2", SUM('my_detail_data'[int_col_2])
        ),
        [summ_col_1], DESC,
        [summ_col_2], DESC
    )

I've also tried a variation where the DAX table does NOT do TOPN, but just does the basic filtering and the exclusion of zero counts, but again ...... KEEPFILTERS doesn't seem to be working:  it's not filter-responsive.
Here's an example like that code, that does almost everything, leaving the TOPN to a filter:
DaxTbl_2 = 
  VAR temp_table = 
    FILTER(KEEPFILTERS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            FILTER(KEEPFILTERS('my_detail_data')
                , 'my_detail_data'[flag_a_4_member] = "Y" 
                && 'my_detail_data'[flag_b_4_line] = "Y"),
            'my_detail_data'[text_col_to_group_1],
            'my_detail_data'[text_col_to_group_2],
            "summ_col_1", SUM('my_detail_data'[int_col_1]),
            "summ_col_2", SUM('my_detail_data'[int_col_2])
        )), 
        [summ_col_1] > 0
    )
RETURN 
    temp_table

I'm guessing the lack of filter-responsiveness is because SUMMARIZE doesn't include the flag-columns.  But those flags are to be selected at the detail level (in the pseudo-code above, at the level of [int_col_1] and [int_col_2]), whereas I need to exclude zero-counts at the group level ([summ_col_1]).
Suggestions?

P.S. The flags I talked about filtering on, are not the same flags in the DAX above:  flag_a_4_member and flag_b_4_line are different flags.

You are trying to filter calculated tables. That's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148028/powerbi-calculatetable-filter-with-selectedvalue/70148616#70148616

@RADO -- ok, ty -- and I upvoted your answer there :)   I see in your DAX example there, a variable ironically named "FilteredTable" uses CALCULATETABLE.  Is that different from what your comment is referencing?  Bigger question:  do you think I could create MULTIPLE TABLE VARIABLES, where the 1st one is filter-responsive, the 2nd does the SUMMARIZE and filters out [summ_col_1] > 0?  ((And then TOP N can be a power bi filter, or by TOPN in a measure.))  In any case, you're welcome to the bounty, if you give an example to do this with measures ... tables or NOT tables!  Thanks again!

There is a big difference between a calculated virtual table inside a measure (like in my example), and a static table in your data model (like what you have). Generally, calculated  columns and calculated tables are identical to the imported table. Personally, I never use them - it's much better to build them in a data warehouse, or in PowerQuery.

To your bigger question, there might be a much easier and simpler solution for what you are trying to achieve, without using multiple table variables (which are possible). But to help further, I'll need to better understand your data model, data, and desired outcome. Ideally, if you could mock up a simplified version of your pbix file and share it, I would take a look at it. The way your question is currently written makes it difficult to help.

@RADO -- thanks much for your offer ... but it's currently huge (millions of rows imported) complicated, and .... multiple pieces (including this one) are promised for tomorrow ... so I'm going to stay focused on the other promised pieces that are not puzzling me.  If I don't find a solution, then I'll have more time to create a PBIX after tomorrow.  or, if I find a solution, I will post an update!  Thanks much again.

I agree that using a calculated table is not the right approach to solving this problem. I recommend using a series of measures on the table: the measures will automatically updates based on the slicers that are selected.
Here's a summary of the steps I recommend taking:

Create summing measures for int_col_1 and int_col_2.
Create ranking measures for int_col_1 and int_col_2.
Create an overall ranking measure.
Add overall ranking to table and filter the table by top 5 from overall ranking measure AND overall ranking is not blank.
Test by selecting slicers and seeing how the table adjusts.

1 Create summing measures for int_col_1 and int_col_2.
sumCol1 = SUM(my_detail_data[int_col_1])

sumCol2 = SUM(my_detail_data[int_col_2])

2 Create ranking measures for int_col_1 and int_col_2.
col1Rank = 
VAR rankVal = 
RANKX (
        ALLSELECTED (
            my_detail_data[text_col_to_group_1],
            my_detail_data[text_col_to_group_2]
        ),
    [sumCol1],
    ,
    ASC,
    DENSE
)

RETURN IF([sumCol1] <> 0, rankVal, BLANK())

col2Rank =
DIVIDE (
    RANKX (
        ALLSELECTED (
            my_detail_data[text_col_to_group_1],
            my_detail_data[text_col_to_group_2]
        ),
        [sumCol2],
        ,
        DESC,
        DENSE
    ),
    COUNTROWS ( ALL ( my_detail_data ) )
)

Make sure both are Decimal number format with 2 decimal places
3 Create an overall ranking measure.
FinalRank = 
VAR rankVal = RANKX (
    ALLSELECTED (
        my_detail_data[text_col_to_group_1],
        my_detail_data[text_col_to_group_2]
    ),
    [col1Rank] + [col2Rank],
    ,DESC
)

RETURN IF([sumCol1] <> 0, rankVal, 9999)

4 Add overall ranking to table and filter the table by top 5 from overall ranking measure AND overall ranking is not blank.

5 Test by selecting slicers and seeing how the table adjusts.

Original table on left and ranked table on the right

Mock data used for this answer:



text_col_to_group_1
text_col_to_group_2
flag_a_4_member
flag_b_4_line
int_col_1
int_col_2




GroupA
Type1
Y
Y
100
200


GroupA
Type2
Y
N
150
100


GroupB
Type1
N
Y
120
80


GroupB
Type2
Y
Y
200
50


GroupC
Type1
Y
Y
90
30


GroupC
Type2
N
N
50
60


GroupD
Type1
Y
Y
180
110


GroupD
Type2
N
Y
140
90


GroupE
Type1
Y
Y
170
220


GroupE
Type2
Y
N
60
70


GroupA
Type1
Y
Y
300
500


GroupA
Type2
Y
N
250
150


GroupB
Type1
N
Y
320
180


GroupB
Type2
Y
Y
400
250


GroupC
Type1
Y
Y
190
130


GroupC
Type2
N
N
150
160


GroupD
Type1
Y
Y
280
210


GroupD
Type2
N
Y
240
190


GroupE
Type1
Y
Y
370
320


GroupE
Type2
Y
N
160
170


GroupF
Type1
Y
N
0
0


GroupF
Type2
N
N
0
0


GroupG
Type1
N
N
0
1


GroupH
Type2
N
N
1
0




Thanks MUCH, Nick! ... I hope you get the bounty -- the amount of work you did merits it -- but note:  the only thing that I wasn't already accomplishing with filter-responsiveness, is EXCLUDING the text_col_to_group_1 when its SUM of int_col_1 is ZERO.  I have tried your logic anyway, because your pseudo code let me rank to TWO columns, in different directions!  Minor note #1:  I was looking for "BOTTOM 5" on int_col_1, but that was easy to fix by changing DESC to ASC in col_rank_1.  Minor note #2:  my rowcount is huge, so I gave the two RANKs more decimal places (6, I think).

P.S.  I also needed to comment out the ,DENSE parameter, at the end of Final_Rank, or filtering Final_Rank less than 11 would get more than 10 results.

Thank you very much for the feedback. I updated steps 2, 3, & 4 to not rank the zero's from the sumCol1 measure. By settings the table filters to also remove Blank values from the Final Rank measure, those rows should now be removed from your table. Let me know your thoughts on this and if any additional changes are needed.

(A) adding that VAL rankVal = and RETURN IF([sumCol1] <> 0, rankVal, BLANK()) to the col1Rank seems to have no effect, (B) adding that VAL and RETURN to FinalRank, together with the table filters to also remove Blank, results in no rows returned, (C) adding that VAL and RETURN but NOT the filter, of course means that the less-than-11 selection still gives the 0-count rows.  So, it's still filter-responsive, but either keeping the 0 rows, or returning no rows.

I also tried RETURN IF([M2_BotN_Sum_ThVisits] <> 0, rankVal, 9999) in FinalRank, together with the filter is less than 11, but that also gave no rows returned.

Ok, this is WORKING:  put the VAL rankVal = and RETURN IF([M2_BotN_Sum_ThVisits] <> 0, rankVal, 9999) in FinalRank, and then instead of using a filter is less than 11, use a TOP N filter, filtering text_col_to_group_1 for Bottom 10 of FinalRank :)  Thanks again MUCH for your help.  Are you up for editing so that the answer matches? ... for the sake of others with similar problems ...?  If you do, then please comment-out or remove the DENSE in your FinalRank, and change DESC to ASC in col1Rank.  Ty ty ty :)

Updated the answer! I believe I've captured all your feedback, but please let me know if I missed anything. If everything looks good, please accept this as the answer.

Thanks much again, Nick!  I accepted the answer, and upvoted it, so I anticipate your reputation gain soon :)))  FYI, if you're up for a trivial correction:  on step 2, the col1Rank has a mis-spelling of BLANK as 'BLAN';  so, you might either correct the spelling, or ... since that line wasn't doing anything up or down, for me, I just removed it.  So, I removed both of these lines:  VAR rankVal = and
RETURN IF([sumCol1] <> 0, rankVal, BLAN())

Ok, I got a reminder from StackOverflow to award the bounty ... and that's when I found out I had to CLICK THE BOUNTY BUTTON :)  I'm not sure whether it got added to your rep, yet -- let me know if any problem.  And thanks again!  (FYI, see my most recent comment, immediately above, if you're up for minor fine-tuning in this answer.)
