Table SUMMARIZE is not filtered by slicers
I wrote a code which works almost fine - I return calculated table with Top 5 Customers along with Total Quantity. The issue is that this table is not filtered by slicers at all (e.g. Date slicers and others). Here is my code:
VAR vTop5CustomersKeys =
TOPN(
    5,
    FILTER(
        VALUES('Customer'),
        'Customer'[Name] <> BLANK() 
       ),
    [Total Ordered Amount],
    DESC
    )

RETURN
    SUMMARIZE(
        vTop5CustomersKeys,
        'Customer'[Name],
        "Total Ordered Amount", [Total Ordered Amount]
    )

I tried to embrace SUMMARIZE with CALCULATETABLE but in vain. I tried with ALLSELECTED('Customer') instead of VALUES but it doesn't change anything. Where is the problem? I'm really struggling to find it out

Might be a modeling issue. This code returns a table.
Are you sure you connected that table to the model, and specifically to your Date table and the dimensions you need?

Yes, in fact I return a table, that's correct. The issue is, that this table is not filtered by any dimensions/slicers. I don't know what's wrong. You wrote about connecting to model - how is it possible to connect calculated table to model?

Go to Table View -> New Table -> paste your code. That way a new entity in your model will be created. Then you can create relationships. I see you don't have date in your new table columns, so you might want to add that there too.

Another way is to use rank function and apply topN in your visuals. That way you will not need to create a new table. If you send pbix with sample data, I will try to come up with solutions.

I thought that If we properly managed filter context in code then creating relationship to fact table is not necessary. Do we need it here? Ok, I will send you but can't find your email address on LinkedIn or wherever, how to send it to you?

Yes, it is necessary to have relationships + date column and other columns you need your data filtered by in the table as well... Otherwise, your table will only return 1 result - regardless of any filters you want to apply. My email is ttruhcheva1@gmail.com. Or you can upload to Drive and send a link over here, so others can try to work on the file as well

I sent via email, thanks in advance!

Calculated tables and columns cannot be filtered by slicers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148028/powerbi-calculatetable-filter-with-selectedvalue/70148616#70148616
