Power BI matrix report not showing dynamic data for Total as per slicer selection
I am working on a power BI matrix report where i have category and manufacturer as its rows and various columns from PrimaryDatatable as values
Attaching the PrimaryDataTable DAX query below.
I also have a slicer that shows categor_PRE from primarydatatable. Now as seen in screenshot we have various categories and their specific manufacturers displayed under it.
Now my requirement is to also show a TotalAisle category along with other categories which is nothing but it displays all manufacturers of this table without category.
Now the issue is when i select some categories in slicer then it correctly displays data for selected categories only but the issue is TotalAisle always remains same. for eg it'll also show manufactuerers and data of those for whom the category is not selected in slicer. How to make this TotalAisle dynamic.
Please help
DAX
PrimaryDataTable = 
VAR Table1 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        ShampooTable,
        "Name_PRE", ShampooTable[Name_PRE],
        "Brand_PRE", ShampooTable[Brand_PRE],
        "Manufacturer_PRE", ShampooTable[Manufacturer_PRE],
        "APM_PRE", ShampooTable[APM_PRE],
        "Name_POST", ShampooTable[Name_POST],
        "Brand_POST", ShampooTable[Brand_POST],
        "Manufacturer_POST", ShampooTable[Manufacturer_POST],
        "APM_POST", ShampooTable[APM_POST],
        "Object_PRE", ShampooTable[Object_PRE],
        "Facings_PRE", ShampooTable[Facings_PRE],
        "Category_PRE", ShampooTable[Category_PRE],
        "SubCategory_PRE", ShampooTable[SubCategory_PRE],
        "width_PRE", ShampooTable[width_PRE],
        "Object_POST", ShampooTable[Object_POST],
        "Facings_POST", ShampooTable[Facings_POST],
        "Category_POST", ShampooTable[Category_POST],
        "SubCategory_POST", ShampooTable[SubCategory_POST],
        "width_POST", ShampooTable[width_POST],
        "Source", "Shampoo"
    )

VAR AggregatedTable1 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ShampooTable,
        ShampooTable[Name_PRE],
        ShampooTable[Brand_PRE],
        ShampooTable[Manufacturer_PRE],
        ShampooTable[APM_PRE],
        ShampooTable[Name_POST],
        ShampooTable[Brand_POST],
        ShampooTable[Manufacturer_POST],
        ShampooTable[APM_POST],
        "Object_PRE", BLANK(), // Set to BLANK() as not aggregating
        "Facings_PRE", SUM(ShampooTable[Facings_PRE]),
        "Category_PRE", "TotalAisle", // Set Category to "TotalAsile"
        "SubCategory_PRE", BLANK(), // Set to BLANK() as not aggregating
        "width_PRE", SUM(ShampooTable[width_PRE]),
        "Object_POST", BLANK(), // Set to BLANK() as not aggregating
        "Facings_POST", SUM(ShampooTable[Facings_POST]),
        "Category_POST", "TotalAisle", // Set Category to "TotalAsile"
        "SubCategory_POST", BLANK(), // Set to BLANK() as not aggregating
        "width_POST", SUM(ShampooTable[width_POST]),
        "Source", "Shampoo"
    )

VAR Table2 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        SoapTable,
        "Name_PRE", SoapTable[Name_PRE],
        "Brand_PRE", SoapTable[Brand_PRE],
        "Manufacturer_PRE", SoapTable[Manufacturer_PRE],
        "APM_PRE", SoapTable[APM_PRE],
        "Name_POST", SoapTable[Name_POST],
        "Brand_POST", SoapTable[Brand_POST],
        "Manufacturer_POST", SoapTable[Manufacturer_POST],
        "TimeLine", SoapTable[TimeLine],
        "APM_POST", SoapTable[APM_POST],
        "Object_PRE", SoapTable[Object_PRE],
        "Facings_PRE", SoapTable[Facings_PRE],
        "Category_PRE", SoapTable[Category_PRE],
        "SubCategory_PRE", SoapTable[SubCategory_PRE],
        "width_PRE", SoapTable[width_PRE],
        "Object_POST", SoapTable[Object_POST],
        "Facings_POST", SoapTable[Facings_POST],
        "Category_POST", SoapTable[Category_POST],
        "SubCategory_POST", SoapTable[SubCategory_POST],
        "width_POST", SoapTable[width_POST],
        "Source", "Soap"
    )

VAR AggregatedTable2 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        SoapTable,
        SoapTable[Name_PRE],
        SoapTable[Brand_PRE],
        SoapTable[Manufacturer_PRE],
        SoapTable[APM_PRE],
        SoapTable[Name_POST],
        SoapTable[Brand_POST],
        SoapTable[Manufacturer_POST],
        SoapTable[APM_POST],
        "Object_PRE", BLANK(), // Set to BLANK() as not aggregating
        "Facings_PRE", SUM(SoapTable[Facings_PRE]),
        "Category_PRE", "TotalAisle", // Set Category to "TotalAsile"
        "SubCategory_PRE", BLANK(), // Set to BLANK() as not aggregating
        "width_PRE", SUM(SoapTable[width_PRE]),
        "Object_POST", BLANK(), // Set to BLANK() as not aggregating
        "Facings_POST", SUM(SoapTable[Facings_POST]),
        "Category_POST", "TotalAisle", // Set Category to "TotalAsile"
        "SubCategory_POST", BLANK(), // Set to BLANK() as not aggregating
        "width_POST", SUM(SoapTable[width_POST]),
        "Source", "Soap"
    )

RETURN
    UNION(
        Table1,
        AggregatedTable1,
        Table2,
        AggregatedTable2
    )
enter image description here
MAtrix report pic attached[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/LhMzwC2d.png


calculated tables do not respond to slicers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148028/powerbi-calculatetable-filter-with-selectedvalue/70148616#70148616
